# What is the transformation of the tangent vector field of a curve under the one-parameter diffeomorphism group generated by a vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism, tangent-spaces

Suppose $\gamma$ is a curve on a smooth differentiable manifold M, with tangent vector field $\xi^a$. Let $\alpha^a$ denote a complete vector field on M. From the integral curves of $\alpha^a$, we can define a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $\Gamma_s: M \to M$ defined such that $\Gamma_s(p) = \Gamma(s, p)$, where the latter is simply the point that is $s$ units along the integral curve of $\alpha^a$ that starts at $p$.

Now apply the diffeomorphism to $\gamma$, so $\gamma \to \gamma' = \Gamma_s(\gamma)$. **How does de tangent vector field $\xi^a$ transform?** Let $\xi'^a$ denote the tangent vector field to $\gamma'$, then how is this related to the original tangent vector field?

Specifically, is there always some $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\xi'^a = \xi^a + \alpha^a$? If not, when does such an $s$ exist?

Comment: I am not sure, which type of answer you would expect. You can express things in terms of the tangent map of flow map of the vector field, but I don't think that this can be made explicit in general. The specific question in the end does not really make sense, since you are trying to relate tangent vectors at different points.

Comment: Dear Andreas, thanks for your answer. I was just wondering if there was any simple expression for $\xi'^a$ that involves $\alpha^a$. I see the specific question was ill-posed, thanks for pointing that out. Actually, I am particularly interested in the way geodesics transform. So suppose that $\gamma$ is a geodesic of $\nabla$, i.e. $\xi^n \nabla_n \xi^a = 0$. Generally, $\gamma'$ is not a geodesic of the same $\nabla$, of course. Question: does there exist a simple expression for $\xi'^n \nabla_n \xi'^a$ in terms of $\alpha^a$? I would be grateful for your response!

Comment: I don't think so, this is a very complicated problem. Usually, one just works infinitesimally with variations. As I said, it is hard to imagine what an answer could look like.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very grateful for your help. If you don't mind, I have one final question. Do you know if there is any way to find a diffeomorphism $d$ such that $\xi'^n \nabla_n \xi'^a = \alpha^a$? As before, $\xi^a$ is the tangent vector field to some geodesic of $\nabla$, $\xi'^a$ is the tangent vector field to $\gamma' := d \circ \gamma$, and $\alpha^a$ is a complete vector field on $M$.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a strange setup. Why  would you prescribe a global vector field on $M$ (and in addition require that it is complete) if you are only interested in the behavior along a curve. Maybe you should start thinking about what this means for $M=\mathbb R^n$ with the flat metric.